# How can i limit my blogs per page on my website?

Tags: html, web

i want to have around 5 blogs per page but i cannot do that because if i add a new blog i have to then manually edit all files again to make the 1st blog second , the 2nd blog third etc.

How can i automate that so that when i add a new blog it automatically adjust and adds the 5th blog on the page to `page2.html` of my website?

i did a research online but i cannot seem to find any solution for that , i heard it can be done with PHP but cant really figure out how

Comment: Have you even tried to make research ? Have you tried to learn PHP, SQL ? http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Comment: Are you saying i dont know shit?

Comment: I've never said that, but like many posters here, you beg for help without trying by yourself beforehand. StackOverflow is not intended to offer free services if you haven't proved you have searched a little bit. When learning PHP, creating a fake blog site is one of the earliest tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this jquery for pagination

http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/

pls edit your selector in jquery code.
selector means your blogs class or Id
if your blog have class ".classname"
if your blog have id "#id"
Note:firt add jquery.min.js
i hope this one is helping u